# Why does the entropy $H(X)$ of a random variable need units whereas the probability of an event is a unitless quantity?

Tags: information-theory

In Elements of Information Theory by Thomas and Cover, the entropy of a random variable is defined by
$$H(X) = \sum_x p(x) \log p(x)$$
where the units are bits if the log base is 2 and nats if the log base is $e$.

Why do we need units at all here? Especially since $p(x)$ has no units.

Comment: It's the logarithm that has units, sort of, not the probability.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan could you please say more?

Comment: Note that if you use the formula $\log_b(x) =\frac{\ln(x) } {\ln(b) }​$ you'll see the entropies are the same up to a constant factor, so their behavior is the same in the end.

Answer (score 1):

If there were a single way to define entropy (say, $\ln p$), then the units would not be needed. However, since logarithms need to be specified by their bases, we need a way to call out what base is used. This creates the need to give a unit. Probability, by being restricted to $[0,1]$ has no such problem.

Comment: yes and there is the operational meaning of entropy, say in terms of data compression, where using a *binary* computer (bits) the entropy denotes how many bits are needed on average to represent the corresponding random variable. So the choice of base is important.